# Deserialising JSON with a '.' variable

Tags: apex, json, deserialize, parsing

I am attempting to deserialise a JSON response with some variables that Salesforce is having a problem handling because there is a '.' in the object name (as well as a '.' in some variable names).

Here's part of the JSON file:

```
{
    "gon.features": {
        "gon.app_is_ready": false,
        "show_newcomers_with_featured_field": true,
        "registration_and_onboarding_flow": true,
        "app_tracking_business_model_enabled": true,
        "product_page_enabled": true,
        "show_new_pricing_page": true,
        "change_advanced_search_path_to_markets": true,
        "publisher_portfolio_page": true,
        "app_country_split_page": true,
        "advanced_search_toggle_view": true
    }
```

}

And my JSON deserialise object for it:

```
    class cls_gon.features {
        public Boolean gon.app_is_ready;
        public boolean show_newcomers_with_featured_field;
        public boolean registration_and_onboarding_flow;
        public boolean app_tracking_business_model_enabled;
        public boolean product_page_enabled;
        public boolean show_new_pricing_page;
        public boolean change_advanced_search_path_to_markets;
        public boolean publisher_portfolio_page;
        public boolean app_country_split_page;
        public boolean advanced_search_toggle_view;
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

> Invalid identifier: gon.features

Is there a way to handle for the variables/objects containing '.' in their name? Changing the JSON response unfortunately isn't an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just deserialize into a `Map<String, Object>`.

```
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserialieUntyped(payload);
Map<String, Object> features = (Map<String, Object>)data.get('gon.features');
Boolean isReady = (Boolean)features.get('gon.app_is_ready');
```

If you always have the same prefix, another option would be to simply modify the payload before deserialization to remove this prefix:

```
String payload = payload.replace('gon.', '');
```

Then you can use everything *after* the dot as your property name:

```
public class Gon
{
    public Features features;
    public class Features
    {
        public Boolean app_is_ready;
        public Boolean show_newcomers_with_featured_field;
        public Boolean registration_and_onboarding_flow;
        public Boolean app_tracking_business_model_enabled;
        public Boolean product_page_enabled;
        public Boolean show_new_pricing_page;
        public Boolean change_advanced_search_path_to_markets;
        public Boolean publisher_portfolio_page;
        public Boolean app_country_split_page;
        public Boolean advanced_search_toggle_view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I didn't know that this was possible. Just a quick one (I am new to this), what does payload stand for in the first line of your code?

Comment: @KamilMieczakowski Your JSON data. The string that you specify at the top of your post. `'{"gon.features": {"gon.app_is_ready": true, ...}}'`

Comment: If you're going with `String.replace` be careful. Are there any free text fields? If so you may want to change that to something more unique like `payload.replace('"gon.app_is_ready".', '"app_is_ready"')` so you don't accidentally replace the string "gon." in the data. E.g. you wouldn't want **Customer owns a Ford Wagon.** to become **Customer owns a Ford Wa** !